# sharing data between disconnected components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm not creating a react app from scratch, but adding interactive components to an existing webpage. I'm mounting two components, disconnected to each other like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Component1 />, document.getElementById('comp1-root'));

ReactDOM.render(<Component2 />, document.getElementById('comp2-root'));
```

They lie far from each other on the page.

How do I have them to communicate their states with each other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) is what I was looking for.

As per my question, I wanted to have same context for all the components mounted at different locations (dom nodes).

Portals solved exactly this issue. Now, I can have one context component housing all the components that exist on that page. Like this:

```
const dashboardContextDom = document.getElementById('dashboard-root');

const comp1DOM = document.getElementById('comp1-root');
const comp2DOM = document.getElementById('comp2-root');

const Dashboard = () => {
   return (
      <>
        {ReactDOM.createPortal(<Component1 />, comp1DOM)}
        {ReactDOM.createPortal(<Component2 />, comp2DOM)}
      </>
   );
}

if(dashboardContextDom) {
   ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, dashboardContextDom);
}
```

With these components housed in one context allows to easily pass state from one component to another via `prop drilling` and `lifting state up`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options with React:

1. Move `Component 1` and `Component 2` and their state into a parent component, and pass the parent's update state function to them:

```
ComponentWrapper {
...
const updateState = () => {
    //update state
}

return (
    <Component 1 updateParentState={updateState}/>
    <Component 2 updateParentState={updateState}/>
)
...
}
```

2. You cannot update the state of a component that is not a parent or a child without using an external state management solution, such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or the new [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) api/hook. These libraries involve moving all individual component's states to a larger centralized global state, which can be updated and accessed by all components.

Comment: Edit: Added option 1 for simpler cases

Comment: please check my answer